# Split a batch of text files using pattern

Tags: batch-processing, csplit

I have a directory of almost a thousand html files. Each file needs to be split up into multiple text files, based on a recurring pattern (a heading). I am on a windows machine, using GnuWin32 tools.

I've found a way to do this, for a single file:

```
csplit 1.html -b "%04d.txt" /"Words in heading"/ {*}
```

But I don't know how to repeat this operation over the entire set of HTML files. This:

```
csplit *.html -b "%04d.txt" /"Words in heading"/ {*}
```

doesn't work, and neither does this:

```
for %i in (*.html) do csplit *.html -b "%04d.txt" /"Words in heading"/ {*}
```

Both result in an invalid pattern error. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The options/arguments order is important with `csplit`. And it won’t accept multiple files. It’s help gets you there:

```
% csplit --help
Usage: csplit [OPTION]... FILE PATTERN...
```

I’m surprised your first example works for the single file. It really should be changed to:

```
% csplit  -b "%04d.txt"  1.html  "/Words in heading/" "{*}"
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            OPTS/ARGS     FILE    PATTERNS
```

Notice also that I changed your your quoting to be *around* the arguments. You probably also need to have quoted your last `"{*}"`.

I’m not sure what shell you’re using, but if that for-loop syntax is appropriate, then the fixed command should work in the loop.

Comment: @aquadhere Did this answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as accepted so that others can see that it worked for this case.